# Understanding what "greater than or equal" and "less than or equal" are in Auto Layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

suppose I have this layout:

[image]

I would like to set contraint from trailing of the color view to the superview in such a way that when the label expands, it will push the colored view to the right, but not exceeding the screen.

So, what I understand is, setting trailing of the colored view to superview with less than or equal relationship will do the trick. But it does not.

[image]

So, what is really the use of greater than or equal and less than or equal anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

set color view's `trailing constraint` to `greater than or equal to` some constant! And it will manage space equal to that constant!

Your label should be self sizing, I mean should increase width with content and you should give fixed width to your color view!

Comment: I would make sure to state that the greater than constraint needs to be between the color view and the super view. Not the label.

Comment: yeah, I am telling about color view's trailing constraint!